# Using Restangular with Rails Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, restangular

EDIT: Restangular depends on Lodash or Underscore!! Once I installed Lodash things are working

---

How?  I just want to do a basic hookup to get going...

So here's my controller

```
AngulaRails.controller "BooksController", ($scope, Restangular) ->

allbooks = Restangular.all('books')

$scope.getBooks = ()  ->
  allbooks.getList().then (response) ->
    console.log(response)
    $scope.books = response
```

Here's my view in rails (I'm not messing with routes in angular, just to keep things simple):

```
<div ng-app="AngulaRails" ng-controller="BooksController" ng-init= "getBooks()">
  <h3>booksbooksbooks</h3>
  <div>{{ books }}</div>
</div>
```

You see I'm calling the getBooks() function, as defined in the controller

Here's my rails controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_book, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  # GET /books
  def index
    @books = Book.all
    @pages = Page.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json {render json: @books, root: false, each_serializer: BookSerializer }

    end
  end
```

I know there is some weird stuff in there about the root and serializer and whatnot, but I've also tried just render json: @books     to no avail.

My browser will show the Booksbooksbooks  and then just literally {{ books }}
Here is the error message from my console:

Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=AngulaRails&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Drestangular%26p1%3D_%2520is%2520not%2520defined%250Aa.init%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Frestangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A7%253A577%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Frestangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A7%253A10268%250Ad%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A31%253A451%250Ag%252F%253C.instantiate%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A32%253A585%250Ac%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A29%253A499%250Aa%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A29%253A438%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A30%253A302%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A8%253A276%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A30%253A123%250Ae%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A30%253A181%250Aq%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A8%253A276%250Ae%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A30%253A123%250A%2524b%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A33%253A238%250AZb%252Fc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A18%253A437%250AZb%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A19%253A141%250ATc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A18%253A220%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fangular.min.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A202%253A125%250AjQuery.Callbacks%252Ffire%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fjquery.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A3120%253A1%250AjQuery.Callbacks%252Fself.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fjquery.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A3232%253A7%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fjquery.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A3444%253A3%250Acompleted%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A3000%252Fassets%252Fjquery.js%253Fbody%253D1%253A3475%253A3%250A%0AF%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fassets%2Fangular.min.js%

I'm getting the sense that Restangular isn't even getting used...

EDIT:  Restangular depends on Lodash or Underscore!! Once I installed Lodash it's working

Comment: Never used `Restangular`, so this may be a nuance, but glancing at the docs it looks like your usage of `all` is reversed.  Should it not be `Restangular.all('books')`?

Comment: Yes and yes.... but unfortunately I'm still getting the same error.  The docs on that error say that it means 'failed to instantiate AngulaRails Module'  Which is my specific angularails app

Answer (score 2):

You need to suply lodash, it is a dependency of restangular

in application.js

```
//= require lodash/dist/lodash.min
//= require angular/angular
//= require restangular/dist/restangular
```